# convert column value to a map value in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

Nervous to ask this question.. HATE getting downvoted.. but it is what it is, I've searched and can't find the solution.

What I ended up doing is adding a loop that goes through my searchResults and reassigns the value for the column after the service returns inside the success block  (PSEUDO CODE HERE, I can't copy and paste my actual code, there is an airgap):

```
var myNumberMap = {
  1: "Number ONE!!",
  2: "Number TWO!!",
  3: "Number THREE!!!"
}

$scope.getSearchResults = function() {
  $q.all({
      resultSet : searchService.getSearchResults()
}).then(function(resultData) {
    searchResults = resultData.resultSet;
    for(var i = 0; i < searchResults.length; i++) {
      searchResults[i].number = myNumberMap[searchResults[i].number];
    }
 }
}
```

I was really hoping there was some slick way I could just assign the data result value inside the grid config to be the value in the map?

Something like:

```
$scope.myCoolGridConfig = NgGridConfig.getConfig(
  NgGridConfig.getDefaultConfig(), {
  data: 'searchModel.searchResults.list',
  columnDefs: [
     field: 'number',
     displayName: 'Number',
     value: myNumberMap[searchModel.searchResults.list.number]
  ]
 }

)
```

Comment: Can you post the service call and `$scope` assignment? And a log of what the data is that is received from the call?

Answer (score 1):

If I interpenetrated the question correctly your looking for something along these lines.

```
myMap = {
    1 : "String One",
    2 : "String Two",
    3 : "String Three"
};
```

If the col number is 1 display String One instead of one in the table

Use myMap and look for the prop of col in it to pull the string value

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="col in tempCols">
      <td>{{col}}</td>
      <td>{{myMap[col]}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

If you need to do it towards an object that has no defining index such as the object below.

```
$scope.objectData = [{
  name: "test1",
},
{
  name: "test1",
},
{
  name: "test1",
},
{
  name: "test1",
},
{
  name: "test1",
},
]
```

You can track it by $index + 1

```
 <table>
      <tr>
        <td> Column Converted</td>
        <td> Object name value</td>
      <tr ng-repeat="col in objectData">
       <td>{{myMap[$index + 1]}}</td>
       <td>{{col.name}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Heres a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9kGx07eioeYjDK9Ny6V1) for a better visual

Comment: I'm not using a table, it's a grid with a grid config object in the controller.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few methods that you could take here:

1. Create a [custom filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09) that you apply to your ng-repeat to transform the values based on your map.
2. Store your value map in your angular controller and bind the mapped value to the DOM.

   ```
   // Controller
   $scope.myMap = {
     1 : "String One",
     2 : "String Two",
     3 : "String Three"
   }

   // something.html
   <div ng-repeat='num in numList'>
     {{myMap[num]}}
   </div>
   ```

Comment: I'm sorry, I guess using pseudo code I wasn't clear.  There are several columns defined in an ngGridConfig object.  One of these columns is hypothetically named number.. I wanted to display the string representation for the given number when I do the ng-repeat over the queryResults using the ngGridConfigObject as a template for display.  Your answer did cause me to think of doing the translation inside the success block of the service call.

Comment: Yes formatting your data in the success is a valid method.